# the name 'Url' does not exist in the current context error in Razor webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to do the following in my .cshtml webpage :

```
    @Url.Content("~/")
```

However, I get the aforementioned error.

The only lead i have is the following: I created a new project to test out what was wrong - in it, `@Url` worked fine, so i followed it up (f12). it led to [`WebViewPage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.webviewpage(v=vs.118).aspx). many other attributes contained in this class were not available (`ViewBag` etc..), so I'm guessing somewhere along the line i broke some config.

Comment: In your web.config, have you got `<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">`

Comment: Have a look in your new project's (the one that works) web.config file for that line of code, then compare it to your existing project. Not sure why it would have stopped working though - have you installed any plugins recently?

Comment: i've added `@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` (i'm assuming this is equivalent). i now get `view Type does not inherit from 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPage'`

Comment: I don't know if it is equivalent. It's better to have in the config file otherwise you'll have to add it to EVERY cshtml file.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error and I had the `<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">` properly seated, and what solved my problem was

1. Close Visual Studio
2. Delete Temporary Files from here

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\{Framework Version}\Temporary ASP.NET Files`

3. Start VS, Right-click your project and click clean-project and re-build.